# How do I add an h1 element to a grid cell so that the h1 does not overlap

Tags: html, css

I'm just starting to work with grid for a website layout in html. My problem is that when creating the h1 within the grid, it slides out. Strangely, the h1 is not fixed in the grid.

Maybe someone can show me a short example how to get these elements into the grid cell so that they are adjusted

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 1fr 100px;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.gird-header {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.content-game {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

.content-player {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  ;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
}

.content.buttons {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
}

.content-footer {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="grid-header">
    <h1>Mensch Aerger dich nicht</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="content-game">Spiel</div>
  <div class="content-player">Spieler</div>
  <div class="content-buttons">Buttons</div>
  <div class="content-footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because you've allocated a grid-area to the header element and you've not defined it (using grid-template-areas see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) so the browser doesn't know where to put it.  You've also got a syntax error in that you've defined .grid-header in your html and gird-header in your CSS. Remove the grid-area property and rename your class in your CSS and it'll work.

Comment: You also have a typo in your CSS `.gird-header {`

Comment: Putting a "header" at the bottom feels odd

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've allocated a grid-area to the header element and you've not defined it (using grid-template-areas see here [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas)) so the browser doesn't know where to put it. You've also got a syntax error in that you've defined .grid-header in your html and gird-header in your CSS. Remove the grid-area property and rename your class in your CSS and it'll work.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  /* made the first row 100px rather than 50px so the header will fit */
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 1fr 100px;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.grid-header { /* fixed syntax error */
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

header {
  /* removed this grid-area: header; */
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.content-game {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

.content-player {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  ;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
}

.content.buttons {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
}

.content-footer {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="grid-header">
    <h1>Mensch Aerger dich nicht</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="content-game">Spiel</div>
  <div class="content-player">Spieler</div>
  <div class="content-buttons">Buttons</div>
  <div class="content-footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```